# train_test_split unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType' with no null values

Tags: python, machine-learning, dask

I'm trying to use dask-ml with [MNIST data](https://www.kaggle.com/c/digit-recognizer).

When I use Dask to split to train and test sets I get this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

There is no null values in the data.
Did you encounter something like this?

My code:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
# load the training data
train = dd.read_csv(r'train.csv')

# split it to X and y
X = train.drop('label', axis=1)
y = train['label']

# split to train and test
from dask_ml.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)
```

Comment: Try `X = train.drop('label', axis=1).values` and `y = train['label'].values`